# Issue: Android Mobile Native Application Recording issue

Tags: android, jmeter, native

Android mobile native application recording issue

- Step 1: Laptop and Android phone are on the same wifi network.
- Step 2: Android phone is configured as the following:
- Manual: IP set to Laptop (IP4) and Port is set to JMeter port 8888
- Step 3: Started recording
- Step 4: Started performing actions on the Android native application.

Observations:

- Native App recording failed.

Additional Info: I am able to record actions on the Android Web Browser

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're running [Android 7.0](https://www.android.com/versions/nougat-7-0/) or higher most probably it's the matter of [increased network security config](https://www.nowsecure.com/blog/2018/08/15/a-security-analysts-guide-to-network-security-configuration-in-android-p/) so you need to [follow some extra steps in order to be able to record secure traffic using JMeter proxy server](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285357-Recording-Using-Android-Devices-Recording-Using-Android-Devices), to wit:

1. Add the next line to the `application` section of your [Android app manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro) file:

   ```
   android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
   ```
2. Create `network_security_config.xml` file under your [app resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources) folder and put the following code inside:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <network-security-config>
       <debug-overrides>
           <trust-anchors>
               <!-- Trust user added CAs while debuggable only -->
               <certificates src="user" />
           </trust-anchors>
       </debug-overrides>
   </network-security-config>
   ```
3. [Compile and install your application in debug mode](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#DebugMode) like:

   ```
   gradlew installDebug
   ```